# Postgres on compute and login nodes on HPC

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I'm using a High Performance Computer with postgres I installed and store locally. I've created a database and I start the psql server in the background with this command:

`postgres -D /scratch/username/psql/SDB >logfile 2>&1 &`

On a login node I can browse and add to the database.

However, when I start the server on a compute node (using the above command) and feed data to it the database doesn't have anything I've done on a login node.

I.e. Everything I do on a login node is only viewable on a login node and everything I do on a compute node is only viewable on the compute nodes.

Why isn't the database one-and-the-same when they are started from the same directory?

Comment: Side note - there is `pg_ctl` to start/stop postgres and manage its logging: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pg-ctl.html

Comment: You did commit your transaction, right?

Comment: @JakubKania Yes, because I can interact with the database if I query it from the compute or login node I entered the data from.